# install-package with chocolatey never adds anything to the path environment variable

Tags: powershell, chocolatey

The command `install-package <packagename> -providerName chocolatey` never seems to add anything to the `PATH` envirnoment variable (Windows 10 Build 15063).

For example running

```
install-package docfx -providerName chocolatey
install-package wkthmltopdf -providerName chocolatey
```

does not do it. Where as

```
choco install docfx
choco install wkhtmltopdf
```

does it. When I run the latter the commands `docfx` and `wkhtmltopdf` are available in the command line.

So my question is: How is installation different when using the `choco` command directly compared to `install-package` and what can I do about this?

Comment: Do you mean the same session the install runs in or isnn't the path extended at all? I know that chocolatey issues `RefreshEnv.exe` to get the changed path in the current session.

Comment: I just found out that I have a folder `c:\chocolatey` and `c:\programdata\chocolatey` and I only have an entry for `c:\programdata\chocolatey` in my `path`

Comment: If the path really is `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin`  - that's normal.

Comment: But install-package installs everything to c:/chocolatey

Comment: Sorry ignore my comments, never used install-package with -providerName chocolatey. BTW Install-Package has a -Destination parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Rob Reynolds pointed out to me on [gitter](https://gitter.im/chocolatey/choco) that package provider is not ready for prime time:

> do not use the
>   prototype provider for OneGet/PackageManagement - it's not official,
>   it's a non-fully featured prototype made by MS and it may have
>   security issues. See
>   https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey-oneget/issues/5#issuecomment-275404099
>   for details